# in org-mode, how to instruct save-some-buffers to ignore Agenda buffers?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Emacs org-mode, I use the command `save-some-buffers` as a default save command to save all the buffers I've been working with. How do I instruct Emacs to not prompt me to save my `Calendar` and `Org Agenda` buffers?

Comment: According the doc of `save-some-buffers`, it will "Save some modified file-visiting buffers". So `Calendar` and `Org Agenda` will not be processed. Do you encounted any problem?

Answer (score 1):

If these are file buffers, then you can tell Emacs to save them without prompting by setting `buffer-save-without-query` (of course, you only want to set it buffer-locally in those buffers).  And if these aren't file buffers, then Emacs prompts you only if `buffer-offer-save` is non-nil in that buffer, so you can avoid the prompt by setting that variable back to its nil default (in which case it won't save those buffers for you).

Comment: In Aquamacs, after I launch org-agenda, then I can't `save-some-buffers` or `save-buffers-kill-terminal` without it prompting me to save random buffers. This does not occur in GNU Emacs. But in GNU Emacs, it now prompts me to save my `.bbdb` buffer.